# pass string containing white spaces in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div class like this and want to call setlocation function which will set the value of the state in the text box

```
<div class="overview over_widt">
    <ul>
        <li class="auto" title="All India"></li>
        {% for state_obj in state_list %}
            <li name="state" class="auto" title="{{state_obj.name}}"><a href="#{{state_obj.id}}" onclick=javascript:setlocation("{{state_obj.name}}")> {{ state_obj.name }}</a></li>
         {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

my java script function

```
function setlocation(name){
    //alert(name);
    $('#id_autocomplete').val(name);
    document.getElementById('city_state').style.display="none"
}
```

and my textbox

```
<input type="text" class="text2" name="location" id="id_autocomplete" placeholder="Enter Location" onfocus="show_div();" onkeyup="div_autocomplete()"/>
```

The problem is I have some states which have "whitespaces" in them and passing those parameters is creating a problem . I tried passing the object also like

```
onclick=javascript:setlocation("{{state_obj}}")
```

but this also doesnt work.

Comment: "_passing those parameters is creating a problem_" and what is the **problem** exactly?

Comment: Use `encodeURIComponent` to encode the string and pass that to setlocation.

Comment: onclick="javascript:setlocation('{{state_obj.name}}')"

Comment: Note that the `javascript:` label is completely unnecessary there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to put the HTML attribute value in quotation marks:

```
onclick="setlocation('{{state_obj.name}}')"
```

Otherwise values with whitespace will mess up your HTML. If you don't use quotation marks, then only the characters up to the next whitespace are considered to be part of the value. So if the generated HTML was

```
onclick=setlocation("foo bar")
```

Then you would have an attribute `onclick` with value `setlocation("foo` and a *boolean attribute* `bar")` (though this would probably be invalid, I don't think attribute names can contain `"` or `)`).

But really, instead of using inline event handlers, you could use [*event delegation*](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) or [any other way of binding event handlers](http://learn.jquery.com/events/).

Comment: If you explain the downvote, I can improve my answer. Without an explanation, there is little I can do. Thank you!